# How to calculate SNR of signals in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signals, noise

I've encountered a very simple, yet fundamental problem on calculating the SNR:

There are several signals :

- S1 = original and pure clean signal without noise.
- N1 = white Gaussian noise which is going to be added to S1.
- S2 = S1 + N1 (the noisy signal before performing the noise-reduction algorithm)
- S3 = noise-reduced signal (after performing noise reduction algorithm)
- N2 = S3 - S1 (the amount of noise after performing the noise-reduction algorithm)

Now I want to compare the SNR before and after performing the noise-reduction algorithm.

1. Which signals should I consider for SNR_before!? **S1/N1** or **S2/N1** ?
2. Which signals should I consider for SNR_after!? **S3/N1** or **S3/N2** ?
3. Which commands or functions should I use in MATLAB in order to compute SNR_before and SNR_after?

Thanks a billion for putting your time on helping me.

Comment: Oh no no not factorial !! sorry for putting so many marks !! I just meant "?" nothing more !! ;)

Answer (score 1):

What i know about calculating snr before :

snrBeforeNoise = mean( signal .^ 2 ) / mean( noise .^ 2 );

and about snr after :

residual_noise = signal - noise_reduced_signal; 
snr_after = mean( signal .^ 2 ) / mean( residual_noise .^ 2 );

Comment: Thanks Danny for your reply. But here in my case, I have several options which confuses me! Before the algorithm, which one should I consider: S1/N1 or S2/N1 ? And after the algorithm should I consider S3/N1 or S3/N2 ?

Comment: By the way, for computing the SNR, we should compute the power of the signal, right !? so is "mean" correct !?

Comment: for before, it is s2/s1 because s2 is your signal with noise included and before noise reduction.

Comment: The more accurate thing to do would be to calculate s1/n1, but in most cases you don't have s1, only s2. However if you have a high SNR it is negligible, and you can always fix it since s2/n1 equals s1/n1 + 1 (in linear calculations).

Comment: Thanks wakjah. I'll definitely calculate the SNR using 10*log10(), but only after I understand which one to choose!!

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Actually I have access to both S1 and S2. However, I'm not sure S1/N1 would be correct; because S1 doesn't contain noise. Are you sure about it !?

Comment: By the way, does anybody have any opinion about SNR_after !? This one is more confusing to me than the "before" one !!